# Applying script to multiple IDs through getElementByID

Tags: javascript, charts, progress-bar

I'm attempting to create bar graphs/progress bars to multiple IDs throughout. But for some reason I'm stumped.

```
        var bar = document.getElementById("chart1", "chart2", "chart3");
        var progress = document.getElementById("progress1", "progress2", "progress3").innerHTML;
        function setProgress(percent){
            bar.style.width = percent + "%";

            if (percent > 70)
                bar.className = "graph graph-green";
            else if (percent > 40)
                bar.className = "graph graph-yellow";
            else if (percent > 0)
                bar.className = "graph graph-red";
        }

        var interval = setInterval(
            function(){
                setProgress(progress);
            }, 100);
```

Any help would be awesome.

Comment: `getElementById` takes only one argument.

Comment: I understand that. Any way to work around that by creating an array and applying it?

Comment: That's how you do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Blender said, [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById) only accepts a single argument, and returns an element.

You can extract that functionality into a function:

```
function applybar(bar,progressElem) {
    var progress = progressElem.innerHTML;

    function setProgress(percent) {
        bar.style.width = percent + "%";

        if (percent > 70) bar.className = "graph graph-green";
        else if (percent > 40) bar.className = "graph graph-yellow";
        else if (percent > 0) bar.className = "graph graph-red";
    }

    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        setProgress(progress);
    }, 100);

}
```

Then usage would be something like

```
applybar(document.getElementById("chart1"),document.getElementById("progress1"));
applybar(document.getElementById("chart2"),document.getElementById("progress2"));
applybar(document.getElementById("chart3"),document.getElementById("progress3"));
```

Some cleanup:

```
var interval = setInterval(function () {
     setProgress(progress);
}, 100);
```

Can be re-written as `setInterval(setProgress,100,progress)` , more than that. The interval length could maybe be passed as a param.

Let's alias `var $ = document.getElementById` and put it in an array:

```
var bars = [{bar:$("chart1"),progress:$("progress1")},
           {bar:$("chart2"),progress:$("progress2")},
           {bar:$("chart3"),progress:$("progress3")}];
```

Then use it

```
bars.forEach(function(bar){ //forEach requires a modern browser
    applybar(bar.bar,bar.progress);
}
```

Comment: @JoeyKirk Great, [please consider accepting this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you feel that it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use array and iterate it through your function like below

```
var bar =["chart1", "chart2", "chart3"];

for(var i=0;i<bar.length;i++)
{
  var barElement = document.getElementById(bar[i]);
  // do your task with barElement
}
```

Comment: With this, do you do the same with the var progress?